# How should I modify this code to print a diamond pattern using the letters from a given string?

Tags: c++, string, nested-loops

For an assignment I need to write a program that takes a user inputted string and outputs a diamond pattern using the letters of the given string. (Without using arrays).

For example:

```
> Enter a word: hello
    h
   e e
  l   l
 l     l
o       o
 l     l
  l   l
   e e
    h
```

I've always had problems understanding how to manipulate nested for loops for things like these so I tried to get source code for a similar problem and modify it.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int n,k,c,space=1;
cout<<"Enter the number of Rows..."<<endl;
cin>>n;
space=n-1;
    for(k=1;k<=n;k++)
    {
        for(c=1;c<=space;c++)
        {
            cout<<" ";
        }
        space--;
        for(c=1;c<=2*k-1;c++)
        {
            cout<<"*";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    space=1;
    for(k=1;k<=n;k++)
    {
        for(c=1;c<=space;c++)
        {
            cout<<" ";
        }
        space++;
        for(c=1;c<=2*(n-k)-1;c++)
        {
            cout<<"*";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This prints a triangle made of up of asterisks. Initially I thought I could just edit the variables around a little bit and use the source code to handle the spacing for me, but obviously since I really don't understand how the variables affect the problem in the first place I haven't gotten far. I would greatly appreciate it if someone could explain to me how I should approach this problem.

Comment: You can learn a lot about your program by using a Debugger.  You can have the debugger execute each line, one at a time, and show the values in variables.  A very handy tool to know and use.

Comment: I get the imrpession that we are looking at your homework assignment. Your first solution attempt was to search for existing code which does the requested thing, but did not find any. Now the second solution attempt it to ask StackOverflow to turn some vaguely similar code into code which answers your homework. I propose the third attempt to be writing your own code, based on what you learned in class, on tutorials and own your own work.

Comment: When you get stuck at that, have a look here, it is the most likely way to find help: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions When you are at that stage make sure to show the textutal information of the desired output as text directly here, not as link to a picture of text.

Comment: @Yunnosch I wasn't looking specifically for a copy paste situation. I'm more than willing (and in fact I prefer) to write my own code provided I understand how to go about solving the problem. The issue is my professor is a very hands off "figure it out yourself" kind of instructor and I don't learn that way. Thus, putting me in a situation like this where I have no idea where to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A great way to work with problems like these is to start with a picture such as the one you linked in your question. Now, for the five letter word "Hello", you can tell from the picture that the H is centered at position 4. (Remember, array and string indices start from 0.) The next step is to also look at other examples. For instance, let's look at what the diamond would like for the 3-letter word "cat".

```
  c
 a a
t   t
 a a
  c
```

This time, the letter 'c' is centered at the position 2. The goal of doing these examples is to find a pattern; here, we find that the pattern is that the first letter is always centered at the position `word length - 1`. Thus, there are `word length - 2` leading spaces on the line with the first letter.

What about for the next line? Notice how there is one less leading space and an additional space in-between the repeated letter. Thus, we have `word length - 2 - 1` leading spaces and `1` space separating them.

What about for the third line? Now we have three spaces in-between the letters and `word length - 2 - 2` leading spaces. Are you starting to see a pattern? How about looking at the fourth and fifth lines of the first example ("Hello") and try to figure out the number of leading spaces and spaces in-between letters. **Read below once you have given it a shot.**

*Each time we go down a row, we lose one leading space. With the exception of the second row, each time we go down a row, we also gain two spaces in-between the letters.* Now, can you convert this pattern into a formula? **Again, see if you can come up with a formula then keep reading.**

We have learned that the number of leading spaces is equal to `word length - 1 - row` (where `row` starts from 0) and the number of spaces in-between letters is equal to `row * 2 - 1`. (Notice how this formula properly handles the case of the second row.)

Thus, your code should look something like this:

```
// Word of caution: I have not tested this code.
using namespace std; // Bad practice in production code; used here for simplicity.
// *snip*
string my_word;
cin >> my_word;
int middle_index = my_word.length() - 1;
for (int r = 0; r < my_word.length; ++r) {
  // This code prints the top part of the diamond.
  for (int ls = 0; ls < middle_index - r; ++ls) {
    cout << " "; // Print out the leading spaces.
  }
  cout << my_word[r]; // You can replace this with my_word.substr(r, 1)
                      // if you are unallowed to treat strings like arrays.
  // r == 0 is a special case since we only print one of those letters.
  if (r == 0) {
    continue;
  }
  // Otherwise, we simply need to print the number of spaces in-between.
  for (int bs = 0; bs < 2 * r - 1; ++bs) {
    cout << " ";
  }
  cout << my_word[r];
}
```

Now to print the other half of the diamond, you have to do soemthing similar to above. Remember to start your loop at `word length - 2` (refer back to your picture to understand why) and to decrement your loop index each time. Also don't forget that `r == 0` is still a special case since you only print that one once.

Comment: This is great so far, but I forgot to mention I'm not allowed to use an array. Is it possible to use something like my_word.substr()?

Comment: In C++, you can treat strings like arrays (like I have done), but they aren't actually arrays. That said, you can modifiy `my_word[r]` to be `my_word.substr(r, 1)` if your professor insists. (So yes, you can use `substr`.)

Comment: @J.Kent  You should edit your question and include that info.

Comment: @Isaiah Finished up thanks to your help. Your code didn't quite print the right format, but I just had to add some "endl"s here and there. As for the bottom half of the triangle, fortunately using the same code while decrementing produces the correct result. Thanks for your help.